# Why am I getting this error while creating XCFramework?: While building for iOS Simulator, no library was found in path

Tags: ios, swift, xcframework

I have written the below commands in a script file to create XCFrameworks for both iPhoneSimulator and iPhoneOS like this below:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme "ProjectD" -archivePath "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcarchive" -sdk 'iphonesimulator' SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive -scheme "ProjectD" -archivePath "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcarchive" -sdk 'iphoneos' SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.framework" -output "/Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcframework"

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.framework" -output "/Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcframework"
```

I tried to use this in a project after dragging and dropping it onto the **Embedded Frameworks and Libraries**

When I run the project with a device as the target, it works fine. But when I run it on a simulator, it throws the below error:

**While building for iOS Simulator, no library was found in */Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectD.xcframework***

If I change the order of the archive and XCFramework creation like below:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme "ProjectD" -archivePath "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcarchive" -sdk 'iphoneos' SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild archive -scheme "ProjectD" -archivePath "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcarchive" -sdk 'iphonesimulator' SKIP_INSTALL=NO

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.framework" -output "/Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcframework"

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.framework" -output "/Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcframework"
```

It works for simulator and not on the device with the same error:

**While building for iPhone, no library was found in */Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectD.xcframework***

I have set the **Build Libraries for Distribution** to **Yes** as well. If I try to create them with different destinations(2 XCFrameworks for iphone and simulator) it is working. But that literally defeats the purpose of XCFrameworks.

Am I missing something or doing any of the steps wrong? Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create a single `.xcframework` file from both `.framework`. (that will include simulator and device architectures) To do that run a single `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` command and pass the 2 different .framework files:

```
xcodebuild
-create-xcframework
-framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.framework"
-framework "/Users/Ron/Archives/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/ProjectDiphoneSimulator.framework"
-output "/Users/Ron/XCFrameworks/ProjectDiphoneOS.xcframework"
```

When you instead run 2 different `xcodebuild -create-xcframework` commands you have as a result your `.xcframework` to include only the last `.framework` file you passed, which is for devices. That's why your project fails to run in simulator.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. That was a simple thing I overlooked.